# Toggle Screensaver Ubuntu Server 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screensaver

Can anyone help me to deactivate the screensaver on Ubuntu server 10.10 in shell by editing a file or an specific command?
Remember there is no user interface.

```
setterm -blank 0
```

didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run this in command line can stop the screen saver in Debian, but Ubuntu does not work.

```
echo -e '\033[9;0]\033[14;0]' > /dev/tty1
```